# Safari Develop menu not responding

Tags: safari, performance, xcode-simulator

I've enabled Develop menu but when I click it, it takes around 1.5 minutes to open.

This behavior was not happening at the beginning but started after a while, presumably around the time I inspected my iPhone simulator through Safari.

I disabled cache, reset settings and restarted, but none of these have solved the problem. I have no extensions installed in Safari.

This is the screenshot of the Console app's logs:
[image: Console logs]

Comment: Have you tried deleting Safari's preferences (i.e. `.plist`)?

Comment: @agarza No, how do I do that?

Comment: Generally preferences are in the ~/Library/Preferences folder. There are a couple of Safari preferences there like com.apple.Safari.plist. There may be others that control that preference in other locations in ~/Library or /Library

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting them (total 4 files) but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hair pulling, I finally figured it out.

Checking Console apps logs, I saw a lot of `SafariBookmarksSyncAgent` timeout errors.

So I unchecked the Safari option from iCloud sync options, and it worked. It appears that there's an issue with syncing bookmarks.